# Is $E[ E[V|W]\cdot W \cdot g(W)] \neq 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have two independent zero mean random variables $V$ and $U$. 
Now let $W=V+U$.

It is not difficult to show that
\begin{align}
E[ E[V|W]\cdot W] \neq 0
\end{align}
The proof goes as follows 
\begin{align}
E[ E[V|W]\cdot W] &= E[  V W ], \text{ by orthogonality } E[ (V-E[V|W]) \cdot W]=0\\
&=E[  V (V+U) ]= E[ V^2]>0
\end{align}

> My questions can we show a modified statment \begin{align} E[
>  E[V|W]\cdot W \cdot g(W)] \neq 0 \end{align}  for any   $g(W)>0$ and
>   $V$ and $W$ with symmetric distributions.

Assume that both $E[V^2]>0$ and $E[W^2]>0$ and $V$ and $W$ are not degenerate.

Comment: Why is $E[V^2] >0$?

Comment: Do you mean for what $g(W)$? technically $g(W) = 1$ satisfies this

Comment: You do need to assume $V$ is not almost surely $0$.

Comment: @aduh by assumption. I added this correction.

Comment: @KitterCatter I want to check if the statmen is true for all $g(W)>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we can't.  For example, let $V$ be $\pm 1$ with equal probabilities, while $U = -3, 0, 3$ with equal probabilities.  We get $W =-4, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4$ with equal probabilities and $E[V|W] = -1,1,-1,1,-1,1$ respectively.  Thus $$E[E[V|W] W g(W)] = 4 g(-4) - 2 g(-2) + g(-1) + g(1) - 2 g(2) + 4 g(4)$$
and there is no reason for that to be nonzero.  For example, you might have $g(\pm 4) = g(\pm 1) = 1$ and $g(\pm 2) = 5/2$.

Comment: Thank you for this example. Do you think the result would be true if assumptions are left the same but the distribution of $V$ is assumed to be absolutely continuous?

Comment: No: if you replace the $U$ and $V$ in my example by slightly "smeared" continuous versions, you'll get an integral that is a slightly "smeared" version of the above, with an integrand $h(x) g(x)$ with $h(x)$ negative near $x=\pm 2$ and positive near $x=\pm 1$ and $\pm 4$.  A suitable choice of $g$ can still make the result $0$.

Comment: Would this still apply if you pick $V$ to be something with infinite support, for example Gaussian?

Comment: Yes, it would.  Just smear it out a bit more.

Comment: I am trying to understand what is the intuition behind this counter example.  Is it correct to say that the counter example exists because we have such a huge freedom of choosing $g$?  and had we reduced the space of $g$'s the statement can be true?

Comment: Back in a discrete case, think of what happens if you make $g(w) = 0$ for all but one possible value of $W$, which just corresponds to one value of $V$ and one $U$, and where the $W$ and $V$ values could have either the same signs or opposite signs.  The corresponding value of $E[E[V|W] W g(W)]$ will then be either positive or negative.  Now by allowing any $g > 0$ you're taking an arbitrary mixture of these with positive weights; depending on how you take the mixture, the result could be positive, negative or zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.